# how can i solve the problem of casting type between "angular" and Object–relational database" table

Tags: angular, oracle, api, types, casting

When I try to implement API angular to connect oracle database, I have a perfect display (output) with  a table of primitive attribute(varchar, number), but the problem appears with the Object–relational database(structure col).
I have this message :

```
(node:13552) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:13552) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: DPI-1014: conversion between Oracle type 0 and native type 0 is not implemented
    at DbObject._toPojo (C:\Users\khale\planning\node_modules\oracledb\lib\dbObject.js:48:19)
    at DbObject.toJSON (C:\Users\khale\planning\node_modules\oracledb\lib\dbObject.js:88:17)
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\khale\planning\server.js:57:31

end--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

note : my table in oracle have a ddl:

```
Create or replace type employ_prod under Employes 
(competances services,
activite  varchar(30),
locale varchar(5),
statusEmp t_lestatus,
grad varchar(10) ,
Sup t_employ_prod  /*sup varchar(20)*/
);
```

and the type services define is:

```
create or replace type services as varray (20) of varchar(30) not null;
```

about t_lestatus:

```
create or replace type lestatus as object ( nom_etat varchar(20),  
                                            date_deb date,
                                            date_fin date,
                                            MEMBER function Is_dispo return integer);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: DDL statements for your tables and object types; the angular code you are using; DML statements for some sample data in your tables; and your expected output for that sample data.

Comment: If you don't include **all the code** necessary to reproduce the error we can't help you diagnose the problem. Of course you don't have to edit your question to provide the additional information: it depends how much you want to resolve this.

Comment: Open an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues) and include the SQL to create some data, and a command-line Node.js script that gives the error.